# Form is being submitted by button outside it in the HTML

Tags: html, forms

I have a page with a form and buttons that are separate like so:

```
<form 
     method="post" 
     action="index.php?Page=team_schedule&amp;week_commencing=2018-01-29" 
     name="apply_filter"
>       
    // Select box with onchange submit
</form>

<a href="index.php?Page=team_schedule&amp;week_commencing=2018-02-05">
    // Button
</a>
```

When I click the button it takes the entire `action` value from the form instead. I have tried disabling the JavaScript on the page but it makes no difference.

***Why is the wrong parameter being passed when the button is clicked?***

Comment: Its working! sending the correct parameters. no reason to send wrong parameters, I tested that with your code, still you have the same issue, change button type to "button" instead of "submit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out with the help of [the Validity plugin](http://www.validity.org.uk/) and view source.

I was missing a `</form>` closing element. The Chrome DOM adds this in retrospectively, but doesn't change the behaviour to match the now closed form. `<button>` elements have a default type of submit so it was submitting the unclosed form and ignoring the anchor element that was wrapping it.

Comment: I know this is old, but you should note that a `button` is invalid content for an `a` tag, as in any "interactive content" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a